# Create a function for generating random number in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have to create a function in a SQL Server trigger for generating random numbers after insert. I want to update the column with that generated random number please help what I have missed in my code.

If you know other ways please suggest a way to complete my task.

This my SQL Server trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgEnquiryMaster]
ON [dbo].[enquiry_master]
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
    declare @EnquiryId int;
    declare @ReferenceNo varchar(50);
    declare @GenReferenceNo NVARCHAR(MAX);

    select @EnquiryId = i.enquiry_id from inserted i;
    select @ReferenceNo = i.reference_no from inserted i;
BEGIN
     SET @GenReferenceNo = 'CREATE FUNCTION functionRandom (@Reference VARCHAR(MAX) )
        RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
        As
        Begin
        DECLARE @r varchar(8);
        SELECT @r = coalesce(@r, '') + n
        FROM (SELECT top 8 
        CHAR(number) n FROM
        master..spt_values
        WHERE type = P AND 
        (number between ascii(0) and ascii(9)
        or number between ascii(A) and ascii(Z)
        or number between ascii(a) and ascii(z))
        ORDER BY newid()) a

        RETURNS @r
        END
        '

        EXEC(@GenReferenceNo)

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- update statements for trigger here
    UPDATE enquiry_master 
    SET reference_no ='updated' 
    WHERE enquiry_id = @EnquiryId
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `UPDATE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `Deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @EnquiryId = i.enquiry_id from inserted i;` - it's non-deterministic, one row will be picked arbitrarily - and all 24 others **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Also, a trigger is **really** no place to go create new functions in your database! What's the thinking behind this?? Makes no sense at all..... that function should be created manually at the time the database is set up - and then **used** in the trigger - but certainly **NOT** created inside the trigger!

Comment: what it exactly showing the function is working fine but what is the main problem

Comment: Hi marc_s tnx for your reply can you tell how to change my code to complete my task

Comment: Hi Jonathan I want to update the reference no with that generating number my peroblem is how to get that generated number and update it.. it is updating fine but I want get that generated number

Comment: Why don't you generate the random number *before* inserting to the table ?

Comment: I want to generating it trigger because inserting happeng from several site it may cause if genrate before insert...may be insert request can occur in same time

Comment: Why not just use `NEWID()` or a [`SEQUENCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ff878058.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate random numbers, just call [CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx) which was introduced in SQL Server 2008:

```sql
SELECT CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(5) AS [Hex],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(5), 2) AS [HexStringWithout0x],
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(10)) AS [Translated-ASCII],
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(20)) AS [Translated-UCS2orUTF16]
```

returns:

```
Hex             HexStringWithout0x    Translated-ASCII    Translated-UCS2orUTF16
0x4F7D9ABBC4    0ECF378A7A            ¿"bü<Ý±Øï           붻槬㟰添䛺⯣왚꒣찭퓚
```

If you are ok with just 0 - 9 and A - F, then the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(5), 2)` is all you need.

Please see my answer on DBA.StackExchange on a similar question for more details:

[Password generator function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108439/password-generator-function/108442#108442)

The `UPDATE` statement shown in the "Update" section of that linked answer is what you want, just remove the `WHERE` condition and add the `JOIN` to the `Inserted` pseudo-table.

The query should look something like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @Length INT = 10;

UPDATE em
SET    em.[reference_no] = rnd.RandomValue
FROM   dbo.enquiry_master em
INNER JOIN Inserted ins
                 ON ins.enquiry_id = em.enquiry_id
CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateReferenceNo(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM((em.[enquiry_id] % 1) + @Length)) rnd;
```

And since the function is slightly different, here is how it should be in order to get both upper-case and lower-case letters:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateReferenceNo(@RandomValue VARBINARY(20))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS RETURN
  WITH base(item) AS
  (
    SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL
  ), items(item) AS
  (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM   base b1
    CROSS JOIN base b2
  )
  SELECT (
     SELECT TOP (LEN(@RandomValue))
            SUBSTRING('1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm',
                      (CONVERT(TINYINT, SUBSTRING(@RandomValue, 1, 1)) % 62) + 1,
                      1) AS [text()]
     FROM   items
     FOR XML PATH('')
  ) AS [RandomReferenceNo];
GO
```

And *please* follow the usage shown above, passing in `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM((em.[enquiry_id] % 1) + @Length)`, *not*: `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(@RefferenceNOLength)`.

---

Other notes:

- @marc_s already explained the one-row vs multiple-rows flaw and how to fix that.
- not only is a trigger not the place to create a new object (i.e. the function), that function wouldn't have worked anyway since the call to `newid()` (in the `ORDER BY`) is not allowed in a function.
- You don't need to issue two separate `SELECT`s to set two different variables. You could do the following:

  ```sql
  SELECT @EnquiryId = i.enquiry_id,
         @ReferenceNo = i.reference_no
  FROM   TableName i;
  ```
- Passing strings into a function requires quoting those strings inside of single-quotes: `ASCII('A')` instead of `ASCII(A)`.

---

**UPDATE**

The full Trigger definition should be something like the following:

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgEnquiryMaster]
ON [dbo].[enquiry_master]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Length INT = 10;

  UPDATE em
  SET    em.[reference_no] = rnd.RandomValue
  FROM   dbo.enquiry_master em
  INNER JOIN Inserted ins
          ON ins.enquiry_id = em.enquiry_id
  CROSS APPLY dbo.GenerateReferenceNo(
                                       CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM((em.[enquiry_id] % 1) + @Length)
                                     ) rnd;
END;
```

Comment: hi srutzky i check your answer in Password generator function it's worked for me thanks for u all.....

Comment: @user3396216 I updated my answer with example code, just to make sure it was clear on how to properly use the iTVF from my other answer in this particular context.

Comment: hi @srutzky I have use dbo.GeneratePassword_Real(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(@RefferenceNOLength)) pass  this methode to Generate that reference no but it return Capital letter and numeric letters I need reference No with Capital,Simple Letters and Numeric number what I want to do???  LR2Z4D like this No only returning now

Comment: @user3396216 I_think_ that I understand what you are saying. Please look at my update as I provided the exact definition of the function. And as I stated just after the new definition, PLEASE pass in `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM((em.[enquiry_id] % 1) + @Length)`, and _not_ `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(@RefferenceNOLength)`. Else multiple rows will get the same value, not a random one.

Comment: hi @srutzky I use this SUBSTRING('1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm',  but it's giving syntax error

Comment: @user3396216 I do not understand what you are saying. There is no syntax error in the `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateReferenceNo...` code that I posted in my answer. If you need more help, you need to at least provide the exact syntax error.

Comment: please do me a favor.... Can you give me a update...please tell me where to keep this method and how to keep if I put this method there is giving some error like this          Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure trgRefferencNo_EnquiryMasterHistory, Line 114
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FUNCTION'.

Comment: @user3396216 I had already provided the usage just above the function definition. However, I did just update my answer to include the full Trigger definition showing that usage. I certainly hope you are not still trying to create the function from within the Trigger.

Answer (score 3):

A trigger should be very *nimble and quick* - it is no place to do heavy and time-intensive processing, and definitely no place to create new database objects since (a) the trigger is executed in the context of the code causing it to fire, and (b) you cannot control when and how often the trigger is fired.

You need to

1. define and create your function to generate that random value *during* database setup - once, before any operations are executed on the database
2. rewrite your trigger to take into account that **multiple rows** could be inserted at once, and in that case, the `Inserted` table will contain multiple rows which all have to be handled.

So your trigger will look something like this (with several assumptions by me - e.g. that `enquiry_id` is the primary key on your table - you need this to establish the `INNER JOIN` between your data table and the `Inserted` pseudo table:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgEnquiryMaster]
ON [dbo].[enquiry_master]
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    -- update statements for trigger here
    UPDATE enq
    SET reference_no = dbo.GenerateRandomValue(.....)
    FROM enquiry_master enq
    INNER JOIN inserted i ON enq.enquiry_id = i.enquiry_id
```

Comment: Wouldn't that generate the same random value for all the records inserted? I would go with a cross apply to the GenerateRandomValue function....

Comment: @ZoharPeled: no, I don't think so - I tried this with a *dummy* random functoin - and it gets called for each row that is inserted, and each row gets a separate, unique value - no data repetition to be seen

Comment: @ZoharPeled and marc_s: There is actually no guarantee that a function (regardless of Scalar UDF, Multistatement TVF, or iTVF) will run more than once per query. I have a good example of an iTVF that, in most cases, runs once per line, but I found a query when it did cache the value from `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`. I will post that example in an update to the answer on DBA.SE that I linked to in my answer here.

Comment: @ZoharPeled and marc_s: I have posted the aforementioned update to that other question ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108439/password-generator-function/108442#108442 ) that shows the caching of the iTVF result.